# How to import JScrollability plugin to my VueJS app?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am trying to use https://adfero.github.io/jScrollability/ plugin in my VueJS app without success. I am struggling with importing the jquery plugin code..

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: any reason to use a jQuery plugin in VueJs?

Comment: @Mr.Alien i used that plugin on a previous project and loved the effect, now that i am learning vuejs it seems that's not a so good idea?

Comment: no, they are two different libraries.. so not a great idea to mix two of them unless you are sure there is no conflicting codebase.. but you might get into trouble as your app grows

Comment: thx, i'll try to replicate the effect with vuejs then

Comment: yes, or you can search for vue equivalent libraries

Comment: @Mr. Alien, Vue is more than capable of co-existing with any other DOM manipulation library (Angular, React, jQuery), be contained into one or contain one (or more, for that matter). It's a progressive framework. It was designed that way. So that you could implement it gradually. It can control a button or your whole website and it can completely "ignore" what's inside the parts it moves. That's why it can wrap absolutely anything and it can live inside anything. To tell people otherwise is to ignore the huge effort put into its design and execution. Please, do some research.

Comment: @Wizzardzz, before asking for anyone's help, you have to try something yourself. Without any line of code written, you're basically asking for free coding services (which is not exactly welcome on [SO]). Please, show us what you've got so far.

Comment: @tao thank you for your insights! i was currently just trying to import the plugin and have not started on working on replicating the behavior myself

Answer (score 1):

I snatched the contents of [this demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-To-Animate-Htm-Elements-On-Scroll-jScrollability/) and wrapped it in Vue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    sections: [
      { title: 'jScrollability Demo' },
      { title: 'Slide From Bottom', class: 'reveal-demo' },
      { title: 'Slide elements in', class: 'slide-in-demo' }
    ]
  }),
  mounted() {
    $.jScrollability([{
        'selector': '.slide-in-demo',
        'start': 'parent',
        'end': 'parent',
        'fn': {
          'left': {
            'start': 100,
            'end': 0,
            'unit': '%'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        'selector': '.reveal-demo',
        'start': 'parent',
        'end': 'parent',
        'fn': {
          'top': {
            'start': 100,
            'end': 0,
            'unit': '%'
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
  }
})
```

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;margin:0;padding:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.section {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.section:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #220044;
}

.section:nth-child(even) {
    background: #220044;
    color: white;
}

.section-0 {
    text-align: center;
}

.section-0 h1 {
    font-size: 7em;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.section-0 h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.section .slide-in-demo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4em;
}

.section .reveal-demo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AdferoInteractive/jScrollability/jScrollability.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <section class="section" :class="[`section-${key}`]" v-for="(section, key) in sections" :key="key">
    <h1 :class="section.class" v-text="section.title" />
  </section>
</div>
```

Its original CSS is poorly written (has non-responsive hard-coded `padding` and `height` values) and it's clearly aimed at desktop screens. The simplest way to have a demo running was to copy the CSS here and adapt it, but I strongly advise against reusing it.

I simply wanted to give you a rough idea on how to reconcile jQuery.jScrollability with Vue.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was specifically looking for the `text-reveal` function and I'll try to adapt it in a clean way using your method!

Comment: I am getting `Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"` tho copy pasting your code

Comment: jScrollability is a jQuery plugin. Therefore, before you can use it, you have to load jQuery, load jScrollability and then you can initiate it. The simplest form of achieving that in a Vue application is to load the two outside of the Vue application like you would in any other page. Then, in your `mounted` hook you can use jScrollability. Here's my answer as [a node based app](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-bird-mntyp?file=/src/App.vue). I load jQuery and scrollability in `public/index.html`, before Vue is instantiated.